# I want to install Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 without losing data.

Tags: installation, windows, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I want to install Windows 7 on a machine where I have already Ubuntu 12.04 installed, because I need Visual studio 2010, which can't be installed in Ubuntu. I want to install Windows 7 in a way that, I don't lose any data on Ubuntu.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. First do a backup of your Ubuntu data (/home, /etc, /opt /usr/local)
2. Next create a partition for Win 7 in Ubuntu using gparted
3. Boot your Win 7 CD/DVD and choose the newly created partition for Win 7
4. After finishing the Win 7 Installation you need to restore the MBR
   [See here how to do it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Answer (score 0):

An option you have is to install a Virtual Machine something like **Virtual Box** (which I find the best) but there are others like Xen or VMware.

Virtual Box is available in the Software Centre

A Virtual machine is self-contained environment that is accessible in Ubuntu once installed.  You can intall Windows 7 with out the hassle of partitioning and dual booting and without risking damaging changes to the host operating system.  There are pros and cons to this method and the cons will be dependant on how memory hungry you Visual Studio 2010 is.

If you need to explore this method further [Ubuntu Community Documantation is a good place to start, just click this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)